# Does Pi draw more power when GND is connected to pin 16?

Tags: gpio, pi-4, power, power-supply

Strange question perhaps, but I was wondering if anyone knows if a Pi would in theory consume more energy when the GND pin is connected to pin #16? I have an interactive piece of software running on the oi that changes what video is playing when a switch is pressed and the connection between GND and pin 16 is made.  I'm just trying to understand if my overall power consumption will be different if no one interacts with it, versus if that switch is constantly being interacted with all day.

Comment: Your question is unclear because of this: `"I have an interactive thing with a switch, ..."` Are you following a tutorial, or setup instructions by connecting pin #16 to GND? Exactly ***what*** is the ***interactive thing***? Trying to see through the fog you've laid w/ your question, I suspect the answer depends upon the nature of the ***interactive thing***. Can you explain that?

Comment: All the GND pins are connected together on the RPi board. So connecting to any one GND pin is equal to every other GND pin. https://pinout.xyz/pinout/ground Also PIN#16 is NOT a GND pin.

Comment: @Dougie yes of course I never said 16 is GND. Why would I have a switch connecting GND to GND anyway? Not sure where you got that

Comment: @Seamus edited for clarity. I think you were assuming there was a lot more going on that there is. The info you asked for has no bearing on power, but I’ve added it to satisfy your curiosity

Comment: @dongle: In this case, the answer is **YES**, the RPi will draw more power (but hardly enough to get excited about).

Comment: There is a lot of magical thinking about GPIO pins. CMOS circuits are symmetrical - whether current flows into or outfrom the pin the current from the supply is the same. If a pin is input no current will flow.

Comment: lol petty commenters downvoting the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will the Pi consume more power if a GPIO is connected to ground?

If the GPIO is set to mode INPUT then the current draw will be effectively zero.

If the GPIO is set to mode OUTPUT and set LOW the current draw will be effectively zero.

If the GPIO is set to mode OUTPUT and set HIGH the current draw will be as high as the GPIO can supply (say 50 milliamps).  This will likely destroy the GPIO and eventually the Pi.

Comment: second point isnt true,  if the pin is set to ouput, and set low, the GPIO pin will now sync current through that low pin. (Assuming the connected device is being 'switched' on the low side)

Comment: @ChadG The question was purely about a GPIO connected to a ground pin.  If the GPIO is connected to something else that is a separate question with a different answer.

Comment: I have tested and confirmed that #1 scenario you described is accurate, using a power usage meter